# Mutating Neural Network not going as expected

Tags: lua, neural-network

I am working on a neuro evolutional system in Lua. When creating a generation of networks I mutate a parent network a number of times to create various new children networks. The code goes as follows:

```
    function MutateNetwork(net)

        for i=2,#net.neurons do
            for j=1,#net.neurons[i] do
                --Mutate Bias
                if (math.random()) > 0.30 then
                    mut = (math.random() - 0.5) * 2
                    net.neurons[i][j].bias = net.neurons[i][j].bias + mut
                end

                --Mutate Weight
                for o=1,#net.neurons[i][j].connections do
                    if (math.random()) > 0.30 then
                        mut = (math.random() - 0.5) * 2
                        net.neurons[i][j].connections[o].weight = net.neurons[i][j].connections[o].weight + mut
                    end
                end
            end
        end

        return net

    end

    function CreateGeneration(parent)
        local gen = {}

        for i=1,childCount do
            gen[i] = MutateNetwork(parent)
        end

        return gen
    end
```

After executing the CreateGeneration( ) function, I get an array of new networks as expected, but all of the mutations are completely identical. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same network for all the children. In fact, it is the same network as the parent. Perhaps you should do something like

```
gen[i] = MutateNetwork(DuplicateNetwork(parent))
```

where the new function `DuplicateNetwork` makes a deep copy of the network.